# ctrl alt f1 on chromebook virtual console

Tags: chromebook, virtual-terminal, chromeos

If I have installed ubuntu on a chromebook how do I bring up a virtual console? (there are no f keys)

Comment: Why do you need the virtual console? Usually you can do anything that you could do in there in the normal terminal.

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome OS this can be done with `CTRL` + `ALT` + one of the keys on top of the number keys. [Image of a keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Th5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are no function keys on a Chromebook. Instead, F1, F2, and so on have been replaced with what Google calls "browser buttons". So this action can be done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (as arrow key is F1 key)

These keys, shown below, allow you to perform certain tasks in the browser including:

[image]